# How can I make a video from pictures?

Tags: animation, animation-rendering

How can I make a video from a sequence of still pictures in PNG format? Something like an animated GIF, just in full-color quality video format.

I'm looking for an Open Source solution for windows.

Thank you very much.

Comment: free (as in freedom) is more important than open source and is not the same as open source. not all open source software is free as in freedom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, for this.

Syntax is

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i img%04d.png video.mp4
```

where `img%04d.png` is the pattern mask for a list of image files named

```
img0001.png
img0002.png
img0003.png
...
```

Comment: don't forget to specify a sane video codec and parameters. defaults are rarely what's appropriate.

Comment: For MP4/MKV, defaults are decent. They are horrible for MPEG-PS or WebM output.